# Stream CanRead/CanSeek false + Length&Position threw exception NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, post, stream, webrequest

I am new to this and what am i trying to do is POST a image as byte array to a URL, but i get error when i try to get the response.

Here is the code from MSDN:

```
// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post.   
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(BASE_URL);
 // Set the Method property of the request to POST.  
 request.Method = "POST";
 // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
 byte[] byteArray = fileContent; // my image as bytearray
 // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.  
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.  
 request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
 // Get the request stream.  
 Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
 // Write the data to the request stream.  
 dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
 // Close the Stream object.  
 dataStream.Close();
 // Get the response.  
 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); // here it stops
 // Display the status.  
                Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.  
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
// Read the content.  
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
// Display the content.  
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
// Clean up the streams.  
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

While debugging in Stream, CanRead and CanSeek is false,Length and Position both throw same error:

> '((System.Net.ConnectStream)dataStream).Length' threw an exception of
>   type 'System.NotSupportedException'.

I tried copying to a memory stream, but same problem. Nothing that i found on internet helped me solve this.

Comment: not all Streams are created equal. Some implementations of the stream class don't allow Seeking or getting the length. I think they are called forward only streams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In regards to debugging**

This is normal behavior from a [`NetworkStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The NetworkStream does not support random access to the network data
>   stream. The value of the CanSeek property, which indicates whether the
>   stream supports seeking, is always false; reading the Position
>   property, reading the Length property, or calling the Seek method will
>   throw a NotSupportedException.

**In regards to your MSDN Example**

see [`WebRequest.GetResponse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx)

The notes state

> If a WebException is thrown, use the Response and Status properties of
>   the exception to determine the response from the server.

Although there are lots of ways to use  `WebRequest`

It would be worth while wrapping this in a `try catch` and working out what the actual exception is and what its telling you

```
try
{
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); 

    ...
    ...
}
catch(WebException ex)
{
    // inspect Response and Status properties
}
```

Comment: the try except helped, the error was not related with what was written! thx man

Comment: @CataHotea glad i could help